# iOS Push Notification: Successful from localhost; connection refused in production

Tags: php, ios, ssl, push-notification, connection

I recently followed the instructions provided here:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

After completing the tutorial, I was successfully able to push a notification to my device from http://localhost/ to my device using both certificates (for development and release), using the sandbox and release domains (gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com and gateway.push.apple.com, respectively.)

After uploading the source code and certificates (*.pem files) into production and testing, the connection is refused (error 111).

It's worth noting that I exported only the certificate, and set a passphrase on it.

I think the problem are these certificates. What approach(es) can I take in order to sort out these certificates in production? Or should I be troubleshooting the server?

Comment: create two different .pem file. One from development certificates and other from production certificates. In your php code, give the path of production .pem file and add gateway.push.apple.com.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done. I'm being refused connection on both *.pem files. I'm wonder if I need to deal with the key that was imported into the Keychain Access... ???